# Do defenders have to be on payload for it to move back?

Tags: overwatch

On payload maps, the payload can reverse direction and move back towards the start. According to the Overwatch wiki (http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Escort), "The payload will roll back towards the start if no attacking players are near it." However, I have often heard defenders on streams say "I'm going to get on the payload to move it back." Is this necessary? Or are they just confused?

Comment: There seems to be a lockout period where you can only move it back after the last attacker has left the payload for x amount of time. Especially when it's just a few meters from reaching the checkpoint/goal.

Comment: Short answer is: No, no one has to be on it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The payload will start moving backwards on defense whether or not anyone on the defending team is riding it. It will start moving backwards 10 seconds after the offense leaves its zone of effect. ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Competitiveoverwatch/comments/4mw40e/mythbusting_does_standing_on_the_payload_as_a/?sort=confidence)). It does not gain a speed benefit from having anyone stand on it.

When attacking, it gets a speed boost for every person standing on or near it, up to three people. The 4th person and beyond will not give it any more of a speed increase. Note that this is true when capturing an objective as well.

Whether attacking or defending, the payload will not move (in either direction) if there is an enemy on it contesting.

Comment: We sure about it not moving any faster with multiple people? The wiki page linked in the question says that up to three attackers move it faster forward, which I was not aware of.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, but I'll add some info about what you're describing.

Comment: @DCShannon multiple *defenders* will not move the payload any faster. You can see this by noting only one arrow appears with any number of people on the payload but multiple arrows with multiple attackers pushing it forward.

Comment: If there's an enemy on or IN it contesting. ;) (The tracker tactic)

Comment: I had to edit the main part of my answer because apparently I was dead wrong.

Comment: Hm, that delay may have been the cause of some confusion. It's not moving, you run over to it, it starts. Seems like it would be because you ran over to it.